# Bash : call a function and check return value

Tags: bash, function, unix

I have a simple script that does something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

main(){
        test
}

test(){
        local value=$(test2 "hi")
        if [ "$value" == "test hi" ];
        then
                echo "function executed"
        fi
}

test2(){
        echo "test2 executed"
        echo "test $1"
}

main
```

Basically, I am trying to check the value returned by a `function` and control the execution accordingly. Now, when I execute this, nothing gets printed (not even the `echo` statement in `test2` function). However, when I add `echo $value` in `test` function (after declaration), everything gets printed.

Is there any way I can process the value returned by `test2` without explicitly echoing the return value.

Comment: It's returning `test2 executed\ntest hi`, not just `test hi`.

Comment: Get rid of `echo "test2 executed"` if that's not supposed to be part of the return value.

Comment: Even then it doesn't get executed @Barmar

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/ojZlV7

Comment: by removing echo "test2 executed" also works for me

Comment: Yep, it's working for me now. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Error messages, debug output, diagnostics, status updates and progress info should be written to `stderr`:

```
test2(){
        echo "test2 executed" >&2
        echo "test $1"
}
```

`stdout` should be used exclusively for the essential business logic output of your function. This way, you can capture and pipe the value without getting it intermingled with debug messages:

```
$ var=$(test2 "hi")
test2 executed
$ echo "The output from the function was <$var>"
The output from the function was <test hi>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an exit code in your function, and check it like any other condition.

```
$: tst() { [[ foo == "$1" ]]; }
$: someVar=foo
$: if tst "$someVar"; then echo "arg was foo"; else echo "arg was NOT foo"; fi
arg was foo
$: someVar=bar
$: if tst "$someVar"; then echo "arg was foo"; else echo "arg was NOT foo"; fi
arg was NOT foo
```

By default, the exit code of any function is the return code of the last executed command, unless you explicitly use `exit` or `return`. (in a function, they are synonyms.)

If you need it, you can create much more complex tests -

```
tst() {
  case "$1" in
  foo) return 0  ;;
  bar) return 1  ;;
    *) return -1 ;;
  esac
}

tst "$someVar"
case "$?" in
0) echo "was foo" ;;
1) echo "was bar" ;;
*) echo "was unrecognized" ;;
esac
```

Try it.